# using push registry Alarm in j2me applicaiton

Tags: java-me, midp

I want to make the application where i want to set the alarm at particular time in the day.When the alarm rings the pop up message will came and the one .txt file from the application will move to the server.

Does any one help me how to use set this alarm through push notification.Or is there any other way to do this task without using push notification.
please help me
Thanks in advance